# systemd keeps restarting user session after reboot

Tags: fedora, operating-systems, systemd

Today i recognized running services on my machine of users which are disabled in the companys ldap. After killing those services the weren't there anymore as i would expect it.

After i did reboot my machine those services are back again. It seems like systemd does start them after the pc is back up and running again.

```
[root@ws ~]# ps aux | grep username
username        985  0.0  0.1  20768 11376 ?        Ss   Aug17   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
username       1007  0.0  0.0  49448  3680 ?        S    Aug17   0:00 (sd-pam)
username       1025  0.0  0.0 226468  3948 ?        Ss   Aug17   0:00 /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d
username       1229  0.0  0.1 229812  8028 pts/0    Ss+  Aug17   0:00 -zsh
```

How can i stop systemd from doing that?

Comment: I've given an answer, but, actually, I don't understand your ps output. This isn't showing services -- it's showing a user session. `username` is actually logged in to the system.

Comment: Yes, in fact those are user sessions of logged out and disabled users which getting restartet after system reboot. Sorry for that confusion.

Comment: Anything in the logs? What about a crontab?

Comment: Crontab is empty, and there nothing in logs which could explain that.

Comment: What _do_ the logs show? Particularly, if you run `journalctl -b` to show entries since the last boot, where does `username` first appear?

Answer (score 1):

The "feature" (which many might consider a bug which one would find in Windows, but not expect it in Linux) is apparently called "linger" or "lingering".

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances

To disable lingering for all users which have it currently enabled, it is according to https://serverfault.com/questions/846441/loginctl-enable-linger-disable-linger-but-reading-linger-status possible to execute

`sudo rm /var/lib/systemd/linger/*`

Now the next question (which needs to be researched separately) remains: how got the lingering enabled in the first place, and will it happen again? Not relevant to this question, since the original poster wrote, that the users are disabled, so it's unlikely they will reappear.

(Re-addding parts of my original answer, which got deleted - @DavidPostill: what is one supposed to do if stack-exchange won't let me comment? Ask a second question which will also get deleted because it is a duplicate?)

The answer by mattdm doesn't help, because (as he wrote) those are not services, but a user session. Started by systemd (or in my case maybe by the Gnome Display Manager) immediately after reboot. WITHOUT the user having been there at the time.

And to mattdm's question "where does username first appear?":

```
Apr 27 18:15:06 hostname systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Apr 27 18:15:06 hostname systemd[2702]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> After i did reboot my machine those services are back again. It seems like systemd does start them after the pc is back up and running again.

Yes. That's what systemd does. In fact, depending on configuration, it may restart services on the fly if you kill them. Its job is to manage process lifecycles, and usually that means making sure things that are supposed to be running are indeed running.

Rather than killing processes, to disable a service, use `systemctl disable service` — for example:

```
systemctl disable httpd.service
```

To have this take effect immediately as well, you can add `--now`, like this:

```
systemctl disable --now httpd.service
```

Disabling a service will stop it from starting at boot, but it won't prevent systemd from starting it for other reasons (on demand by another service, for example). To make a service completely not available ("masked out"), use `systemctl mask` instead of `disable`.